# Execute a query filtered by third combobox column

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to execute a query filtered by third combobox column

I have a combobox with the following rowSource (as example):

```
SELECT Id, Two, Three, Four from AnyTable
```

Bound Column is Id (I need it)

Another combobox needs the "three" field to filter with the following rowSource (as example):

```
SELECT IdTable2,Table2Two,Table2Three from AnyTable2 WHERE Table2Three=??????? 'Need to refer to value of column three of first Combo
```

I tried many solutions, but doesn't work (syntax)

How I could do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Column property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.column).

Column index is 0-based, so you need `.Column(2)`

```sql
SELECT IdTable2,Table2Two,Table2Three 
FROM AnyTable2 
WHERE Table2Three = Forms!myForm!myCombobox.Column(2)
```

Comment: SELECT STT_JLE_Materiales_Grupos_Detalle.Materiales_Grupos_Detalle_Descripcion, STT_JLE_Materiales_Grupos_Detalle.Id_GruposDetalle, STT_JLE_Materiales_Grupos_Detalle.Cod_Grupo
FROM STT_JLE_Materiales_Grupos_Detalle
WHERE STT_JLE_Materiales_Grupos_Detalle.Cod_Grupo= [Forms].[Frm20200_MaterialProveedor_Nuevo].[CboDatosIndependientesCod_Tara].Column(0)
ORDER BY STT_JLE_Materiales_Grupos_Detalle.Materiales_Grupos_Detalle_Descripcion;

Error: not defined

Comment: Don't write code in comments, add it to your question. And the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Eval* for this:

```sql
SELECT 
    IdTable2,
    Table2Two,
    Table2Three 
FROM 
    AnyTable2 
WHERE 
    Table2Three = Eval("[Forms].[YourForm].[cboFilter].Column(2)");
```

Comment: WHERE STT_JLE_Materiales_Grupos_Detalle.Cod_Grupo= Eval ("[Forms].[Frm20200_MaterialProveedor_Nuevo].[CboDatosIndependientesCod_Tara].Column(2)")

Error: not defined EVAL

Error

Comment: Why have you inserted a space?